# scope of a online examination system in uml that is project outline of the project

Tags: uml

i am a beginner in this field. I dont know much about uml. I have to submit a project on "online examination system" using "agrouml". So, any one please give me the scope of the project. How to write a scope of a project? any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: What did you research before asking here...?

Answer (score 1):

A scope could be defined in text or in the partly Use Case diagram. Define Actors - people, who would work with your system (Admin, Lector, Student, Faculty staff member...) For each of them write down their actions they'll do to your system.

In Use case you'll have stick men for actors and ovals for use cases. Connect actors to their use cases.

Call the diagram Scope Definition, for people not to mix it with the real use case diagram. Which it is not.

The full Use Case Diagram should include also the parts of your system, connected to Use Cases "from the other side". But you will have to do it AFTER scope definition and APART from it, as another diagram.